# Assumption of molecular chaos

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Assumption of molecular chaos in statistical mechanics states that the incoming velocities of two colliding particles are uncorrelated.

Now, since it introduces a direction of time, this hypothesis obviously could not be derived from the classical equations of motion for particles (F=ma and etc., or their more mathematically elaborated counterparts).

My question is: are there any logical arguments showing the above hypothesis is compatible with (i.e. does not imply something strongly contradicting) the Newtonian equations of motion, other than that it manages to provide predictions agreeing with experiments?

My own thoughts on this: since it breaks the time-reversal symmetry of the classical model, molecular chaos is indeed incompatible with the classical equations of motion. But this raises the further question of why, then, are we allowed to use classical mechanics everywhere else in statistical mechanics.

Comment: Yes, this assumption is incompatible with the laws of Newtonian mechanics. It should be seen as a convenient approximation, that could be realized in some ideal limiting procedure. I would recommend reading Gallavotti's beautiful book *Statistical Mechanics, A Short Treatise* for a detailed discussion of such issues. He has also [another more recent one](http://ricerca.mat.uniroma3.it/ipparco/pagine/deposito/2013/N3.pdf), which seems to be relevant, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik My gratitudes! The idea of viewing irreversibility as a consequence of a limiting process is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

For systems of point particles, equations of motion in non-relativistic mechanics are such that initial condition is positions and their first derivatives, but not higher derivatives of position.

But as far as values of those positions and velocities go, one can choose any, equations of motion do not limit them in any way. Thus special condition such as the decorrelation hypothesis are fine in  mechanics.

Comment: Sure, but absence of correlations in the initial condition by no means implies absence of correlations at later times (due to recollisions, etc.).

Comment: Where was such implication mentioned?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it, in the question of the OP (it was not specifically about initial conditions). Or maybe I missed the point of your answer...

Comment: I mean, the assumption of molecular chaos is used to derive, e.g., the H theorem (I assume these are the things the OP is interested in). And for the latter, uncorrelated initial conditions are not sufficient (you need, for example, some grad type limit to derive the result).

Comment: @Ján Lalinský I am with Yvan Velenik here. It is with the decorrelation of velocities in the entire dynamic process that molecular chaos is concerned; and it's true that decorelation at the initial time does not imply the same condition for later times.

Comment: Collisions may introduce correlation, but how does that invalidate the answer? The decorrelation hypothesis itself is compatible with Newton's equations, in any time. That there are initial conditions that are not consistent with the hypothesis is another matter.

Comment: I still don't get your point. Even if you choose initial conditions that are uncorrelated, under Newtonian evolution they will almost surely end up correlated. In this sense, the chaotic hypothesis is generically wrong for Newtonian evolution. Said differently, and more closely related to the OP's question, a reversible dynamics, whatever initial state you might choose, can never give rise to a truly irreversible macroscopic evolution. In particular, the chaotic hypothesis, that allows you to deduce irreversibility cannot be compatible with Newtonian evolution.

Comment: (Of course, we both understand well how, properly interpreted, macroscopic irreversibility can be reconciliated with microscopic reversibility; this was already well understood by Boltzmann. It remains that true irreversibility is not compatible with microscopic reversibility.)

Comment: Maybe I see where our disagreement comes from: what you're saying seems to be that this hypothesis can be made at any given time. Right. But you cannot make it simultaneously at time $t$ and at time $t'>t$, because correlations will generically build up from time $t$ to time $t'$, invalidating this assumption at time $t'$. Do you agree with that?

Comment: My point is equations of motion do not restrict initial conditions. They restrict trajectories. We are free to assume the hypothesis for limited time and derive its consequences. Poincare recurrences happen after so extremely long times that they are of no interest in modelling laboratory experiments with gases.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the question is about mathematical compatibility between, on the one hand, the chaotic hypothesis and, on the other hand, Newtonian dynamics. As I already stated several times, they are incompatible. For that, initial conditions are irrelevant. That it is perfectly possible to understand why one can still observe macroscopic irreversibility over any reasonable timescales is another matter entirely. But I will let it at that, as I am not sure discussing more will help.

Comment: I understand your point as equations of motion imply that state of "perfect decorrelation" cannot be maintained indefinitely. I do not think this was the question though. The chaos hypothesis is just a approximation - simplification to help derive what happens without solving the equations of motion exactly. We are free to assume it and derive consequences, even if some system phase trajectories do not obey it, and even if it is not exact for all times. Do equations of motion imply that all decorrelated states turn quickly into strongly correlated state which stays that way?

Comment: Yes, this is what happens generically, as can easily be seen from the possibility of recollisions (which immediately induce correlations). It is of course interesting to understand under which conditions there is *propagation of chaos* (that is, preservation of statistical independence under evolution). A recent discussion of such issues *in the Boltzmann-Grad limit*, in which recollisions are very rare by construction, is given for a system of hard spheres in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-016-0682-4).

Comment: (There may be even more recent works on this, but I do not regularly follow the evolution in this line of work. This is a bit too remote from my own research area.)

Comment: *"this is what happens generically, as can easily be seen from the possibility of recollisions (which immediately induce correlations)."* this is hard to believe or I don't understand. Could you suggest a paper/book where this is demonstrated?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after: recollisions immediately imply that you cannot truncate the BBGKY hierarchy. If you need a confirmation from an expert, I'd suggest this [nice review](https://msp.org/memocs/2016/4-3/memocs-v4-n3-p05-s.pdf) by one of the leading specialists. In particular, read the last paragraph of Section 1. Note that, in most rigorous works, what you do is you try to control the error made when truncating the BBGKY hierarchy at the level of 1-point functions, showing that these errors vanish in suitable limits (low density, etc). They of course do not disappear in general.

Comment: (See also around equation (20) for the case of hard spheres.)
You can also have a look at Section 1.8 and Appendix 1.A.2 of [Gallavotti's book](http://ergodic.ugr.es/FisicaEstadistica/bibliografia/G%20Gallavotti%20SM%20(359).pdf).

Answer (score 0):

First note that it is an *assumption* of molecular chaos. You can see it as a prerequisite to apply statistical mechanics. Does the assumption fail? No statistical mechanics for you!

So does it introduce a direction of time? I think not because whether the particles are correlated or not depends on your initial conditions. You put uncorrelated velocities in and you get uncorrelated velocities out. In equilibrium the system is time reversible because then the entropy doesn't increase and $\text dS=0$. The process of correlated velocities becoming uncorrelated breaks time symmetry sure. But once you have an equilibrium state the system is time symmetric.